¿Como dejar de visualizar mensaje de completar el perfil en stackoverflow?
Soy nuevo en la comunidad pero me quiero mantener de forma anónima.
Al registrarme en la página, me sugiere que complete mi perfil con un anuncio que se torna molesto porque se muestra cada ver que realizo cualquier acción en la página.
Intenté cambiar mi nombre de usuario y la imagen de perfil pero sigo visualizando el mensaje.
Tampoco me ha llegado algún link para validar mi correo electrónico.
¿Existe alguna forma de deshacerme de él?
De antemano, muchas gracias.


Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Pues estuve probando varias cosas, eliminar datos y cookies del sitio, permitir las cookies requeridas, posteriormente permitirlas todas, cerrar el navegador y volverlo a ejecutar pero el mensaje persiste.
Cabe destacar que solo ocurre con la página de stackoverflow en español y no con la página de es.meta.stackoverflow.

Puedes agregar un nombre de usuario y una foto de perfil que mantengan tu anonimato. Sé que, probablemente no es lo ideal, pero lograría que dejes de ver el mensaje que te resulta molesto.

aunque sea importante no veo ningun problema en el banner que te sale ... simplemente tienes que poner cualquier imagen y/o nombre que quieras, siempre y cuando cumpla con las normas del sitio...

Adicional que sería recomendado limpiar el cache del sitio y darle tiempo a que la modificación del perfil se esparza por todo los sitios de la red ...

El problema parece ser a nivel de red. Ya lo reportaron en Meta. Está relacionado a los nuevos cambios en el flujo de registro en los sitios de SE.

Mi imagen de perfil ya está "customizada" al igual que mi nombre de usuario. No es nada grave la verdad pero es bastante molesto que cada vez que actualizo la página me salga ese pop-up.
De hecho puedo incluso estar en un bucle de darle click a "Finish setup" > "Completar el registro"
